# Oracle PL/SQL, I want to retrieve the details of the product which has the price closest to 4.23

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure nearprice
is
  userprice products.price%type := 4.23;
  closest   products.price%type;
  temp      products.price%type;
  tempid    products.pid%type;
  cursor procur is
    select * from products;
  prorec procur%rowtype;
begin
  open procur;
  fetch procur into prorec;
  closest := abs(prorec.price - userprice);
  tempid  := prorec.pid;

  while procur%found then
  loop
    fetch procur into prorec;
    temp := abs(prorec.price - userprice);
    if temp < closest then
      closest := temp;
      tempid = prorec.pid;  
    end if;
  end loop;

  close procur;

  select * 
    from products 
   where pid = tempid;

end;
```

I want to retrieve the record in the `products` table which has the price closest to 4.23.
'products' is a table with `pid` as primary key and datatype of price is number(*,2);
In this procedure I try to find the minimum of the absolute value of the difference between 4.23 and the price, fetched by the cursor `prorec` and print all details corresponding to it. I keep getting

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

I'm new to PL/SQL so can anyone tell me what mistake I'm doing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is with a query:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*
      from products p
      order by abs(price - 4.23)
     ) p
where rownum = 1;
```

You don't need a cursor to do this calculation.

EDIT:

KZ makes a very good point in the comments about the use of indexes on a large table.  The query looks more complicated, but it can use an index:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*
      from ((select p.*
             from (select p.*
                   from products p
                   where price <= 4.23
                   order by price desc
                  ) p
             where rownum = 1
            ) union all
            (select p.*
             from (select p.*
                   from products p
                   where price > 4.23
                   order by price
                  ) p
             where rownum = 1
            )
           ) p
      order by abs(price - 4.23)
     ) p
where rownum = 1;
```

ALthough it looks complicated, the idea is simple.  Select one row where the price is less than or equal to the cutoff.  Select one row where the price is greater than the value.  Then choose the closest value.

Comment: Agree - get out of the RBAR mentality and start thinking in sets.

Comment: This works, but if product table is very big and you consider creating index on price Oracle won't be able to use it with abs. You will need to split this into two subqueries (search for nearest price ascending and descending from 4.23 and choose the closest of the two).

Comment: Gordon, I'm greatly thankful for your solution, yes it worked. And everyone, thank you for your time :)